# Lambda StartsWith to Include null, blank or all values in database

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this code snippet that queries a SQL table that contains first, middle and last names. The model requires a first name and last name but, middle name is optional. Here's the issue with this code that I'm having. No matter what value is entered for a middle name (blank or value present) records that do not contain a middle name are not returned in the result set. Searching for John Smith will return "John M Smith" but not "John Smith". I should also note that the middle name column in the database can contain null, blank or string values. It's an old MS SQL database with a terribly written VB front end.

Code:

```
var query = (from i in ctx.Individuals
     join l in ctx.Licenses on i.IndividualId equals l.IndividualId
     where i.FirstName.StartsWith(firstName) && i.LastName.StartsWith(lastName) && i.MiddleName.StartsWith(middleName ?? i.MiddleName)
     select new IndividualDTO()
     {
         IndividualId = i.IndividualId,
         FirstName = i.FirstName,
         LastName = i.LastName,
         MiddleName = i.MiddleName,
         LicenseNumber = l.LicenseNumber
     }).OrderBy(i => i.FirstName).OrderBy(i => i.LastName).Take(50).ToList();
```

Comment: Some databases treat empty strings as `null`. But we probably need to see the query that gets generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually redo this to only include your conditions when necessary. This way you avoid the null or empty middle name. If the search strings could be whitespace use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` instead. Also you'll want to use `ThenBy` in your ordering to keep your initial order.

```
var query = from i in ctx.Individuals
    join l in ctx.Licenses on i.IndividualId equals l.IndividualId
    select new IndividualDTO
    {
        IndividualId = i.IndividualId,
        FirstName = i.FirstName,
        LastName = i.LastName,
        MiddleName = i.MiddleName,
        LicenseNumber = l.LicenseNumber
    };

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
{
    query = query.Where(i => i.FirstName.StartsWith(firstName));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
{
    query = query.Where(i => i.LastName.StartsWith(lastName));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))
{
    query = query.Where(i => i.MiddleName.StartsWith(middleName));
}

var result = query
    .OrderBy(i => i.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(i => i.LastName)
    .Take(50)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

We wanted to match if the following is happening `MiddleName starts with middleName` or middleName is `empty or null`
This means we want to have our boolean expression to succeed if

`String.IsNullOrWhitespace(i.MiddleName)`
**OR**
`i.MiddleName.StartsWith(middleName)`.

- In case of `middleName` empty or null than this will evaluate `&& (true || Doesn't matter)` which will give us a match.
- And In case of `i.MiddleName` starts with `middleName` than this will evaluate `&& (false || true)` which also give us a match.

**You should change**

```
i.MiddleName.StartsWith(middleName ?? i.MiddleName)
```

**To**

```
(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(i.MiddleName) || i.MiddleName.StartsWith(middleName))
```

Comment: It would probably help if you explained why this might resolve the issue.

Comment: This is including the blank or nulls now but if the optional middle name field is left blank then those that have a middle name are now excluded. Ideas?

Comment: @DaveZych: Explanasion added.